# How to send data bytes through HTTP post to .NET server

Tags: iphone, .net, ios

Setting the form's enctype to "multipart/form-data" causes an exception to be thrown by the webservice.

System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data; boundary=---.....

I need to post the HTML form direct to the webservice, and it can't be hosted by the .NET server.

Any idea...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) to understand what a multipart protocol means.
You need to make the multipart "decoration" by hand, this  code may helps:

```
-(NSData *)makeMultipartDataWithBoundary:(NSString *) boundary 
                              parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                                formName:(NSString *)formName 
                                fileName:(NSString *)fileName 
                                fileType:(NSString *)fileType
                                fileData:(NSData*)fileData
{    
    NSMutableString * res = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];

    for(NSString * key in [parameters allKeys]){

        NSString * value = [parameters objectForKey:key];

        if(![value isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]]) continue;

        [res appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n", key];
        [res appendFormat:@"\r\n%@\r\n", value];
        [res appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
    }
    [res appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", formName, fileName];
    [res appendFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", fileType];

    NSMutableData * data= [NSMutableData data];

    NSLog(@"%@", res);

    [data appendData:[res dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [data appendData:fileData];
    [data appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    return data;
}
```

where:

**boundary** is a NSString (bytes sequence) that doesn't be appear in the fileData section. e.g. 'D33pN16h7abcd'

**parameters** is a dictionary contaning all the header parameters to be passed to the multipart protocol.

**formName** is a identifier.

**fileType** is the mime file type e.g. 'image/png'

Finally **fileData** are the bytes of the content of file.

The next lines shows yo a example to call this method:

```
- (void) sendAllData {
    NSData *data;

    data = [self makeMultipartDataWithBoundary:kBoundary 
                                    parameters:nil 
                                      formName:@"imageField"                              fileName:@"imageExample.png" 
                                      fileType:@"image/png" 
                                      fileData:self.imageData];
    // Make a post NSURLConnection request with the data  

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.org/file.php"] 
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData 
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
    [request setHTTPBody:data]; 
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", kBoundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; 
    if (connection) { 
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain]; 
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your answer is correct with php server but with .net server i was still facing the same problem. so i have used SOAP services for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using SOAP service. Final working code is as follows:

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

```
NSData *imageDataToSend =  [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(previewImageView_.image, 90)];

NSString *imgegeDataStr = [imageDataToSend base64EncodedString];

NSString *soapMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><SaveCampaignImage xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><CampaignImage>%@</CampaignImage><ImageName>image1</ImageName><CampaignID>4</CampaignID></SaveCampaignImage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",imgegeDataStr];
NSLog(@"soapMsg");
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.4.3.224/VerizonDealsWebService/Service1.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/SaveCampaignImage" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection_ = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[connection_ start];
[connection_ release];
[pool release];
```