# Upload image , video and audio file to a php web service in iphone

Tags: php, iphone, web-services

I am facing issues in uploading media files to a web service built in php.
I have an app along with source code in android and I am suppose to replicate it in iphone.
There is this part where I am supposed to upload media files along with some strings to a web service.
         The code in android uses a class called MultiPartEntity and HTTPPost to upload it.
There are several tags , and the tags are associated with some strings.

for ex.MultiPartEntity mpEntity.addPart("username", "abc");, similarly for password and other tags.

I made some research and I found ASIFormDataRequest which deals with similar things.

here is the sample code I am using to upload media along with some other detials,

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.url.com/somephpwebservice.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

```
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// now lets create the body of the post 
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//................................ Append the image data here//u= \"TP\";p= \"7012\";o= \"DEMO\";j= \"1151\"...........................
//if (!([htmlCodeToWrite rangeOfString:@"SignatureShouldBeDoneHere"].location == NSNotFound))
//{
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"userfile\";username=\"TP\";p=\"7012\";filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@"superman.jpg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
//}
//NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[imageData bytes]];
NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//data into the string..... verifying............
NSString *strTest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@ %@",@".....the request for webService",strTest);

// setting the body of the post to the request
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@ %@",returnString,@".....the response from webService");
```

Is this the proper procedure.??

The php developer says the image is not getting uploaded.

Please help.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Any particular reasons why not to use ASIFormDataRequest ?

Comment: I even tried it with ASIFormDataRequest, but no help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to my response in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967832/how-to-send-data-bytes-through-http-post-to-net-server/7968476#comment9775162_7968476) post. I think is the correct way to conform a multipart upload file request. Cheers!